# More concise way to do something a maximum of X times, raising an exception if it takes X times to run the command

Tags: python, exception

Is there a more concise way to perform this in Python:

```
tries = 10
for x in range(tries):
    try:
        foo()
        break
    except Exception as e:
        if x == tries-1:
            raise e
```

The point of it is that sometimes the operation fails (for whatever reason), but we want to allow for a number of retries before raising an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A usual way to make something more concise is to factor it out.

```
def retrying(max_attempts, func, *args, **kwargs):
  attempts_left = max_attempts
  while attempts_left:  # could be 'while True', but an extra check won't hurt
    try:
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    except SomeException:
      attempts_left -= 1
      if not attempts_left:
        raise
```

The above code only catches `SomeException` and not `Exception`, else it would keep retrying when you have an undefined identifier in your code. Usually catching all exceptions is a bad idea, unless you re-raise them immediately. The lone `raise` preserves the `func`'s stack trace. You could pass the list of exceptions to catch as a parameter.

The code above does most sense if you have several places where you need to retry actions. Then you just write `retrying(3, foo, 1, b=2)` instead of `foo(1, b=2)`.

Comment: Just an idea: You could get rid of the `cnt` variable altogether and do `max_attempts -= 1` and then `if max_attempts == 0:`.

Comment: I just used Exception as an example, there is a specific exception that gets caught.

Thanks!

Comment: @iCodez: I usually tend to treat parameters as immutable. It helps debugging (what was the original value of the parameter again?), it simplifies reasoning, and it keeps mutable parameters (lists, dicts, etc) from inadvertent modification as a result of the call.

Comment: catching `Exception` doesn't catch `^C`, `KeyboardInterrupt` only inherits from `BaseException`.

Comment: @roippi: Goog catch :) My initial code had had a bare `except` clause which I then edited, but did not fix the explanation.

Comment: @9000: why did you discard the for loop? To me at least, the variable purpose is more obvious in a for loop. Managing the variable also needs less code.

Comment: @mknecht: mostly because handling the case when all iterations fail was cumbersome with a `for` loop. But loop variable handling can be improved by using decrement, so that the code reads more straightforwardly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
tries = 10
for _ in range(tries):
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    else:
        break
else:
    raise e
```

Comment: Well, your answer uses 9 lines instead of 8, so I would hardly call that `more concise`

Comment: I have managed to add an extra line. That doesn't actually make it more concise, but at least you're not needlessly comparing x

Comment: That's true, and clarity is very important in my case.

If there really is no native python way to do something like this, it's fine.

Comment: and, of course, the obvious way to make it more concise, is to wrap it in a function... i.e. `retry(foo, 10, allowed_exception_list)`...

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same but slightly more concise...

```
x = 10
while x > 0:
    try:
        foo()
        break
    except Error:
        if x == 1: raise Exception('')
    x -= 1
```

Comment: This does not reraise the exception after the 10-th fail.

Comment: and _always_ raises an exception

Comment: I edited the post. Thanks for your comments. I believe this works

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as @9000 solution, keeping it's advantages: encapsulated functionality, preserved stack trace. It changes two things: Using a for-loop instead of a while-loop and counting down instead of up.

```
def retrying(max_attempts, func, *args, **kwargs):
    for attempts_left in reversed(range(max_attempts)):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            if not attempts_left:
                raise
```

For my taste/brain, the for-loop is easier to grasp: a collection is being processed until its end is reached. while-loops always make me search for the catch.

Counting down matches my intuitive understanding better.

A matter of taste, I guess, but for the reasons above I definitely prefer this one.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't this do what you want:

```
tries = 10
for x in range(tries):
    try:
        foo()
        break
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

The first time foo() succeeds you break out and are done.

Comment: The OP *already does this*. The only difference is that you don't re-reraise the exception when the last try failed.